# Where do I find the instance types in the new console?

Tags: google-app-engine

In the old appengine console I can see the instance types in the versions settings:

instance_class: F2 
idle instances: [auto, 1] | pending latency: [auto, auto] | max concurrent requests: auto

Where do I find this info in the new developer consonle?

Answer (score 8):

App Engine -> Versions -> Show all columns

[image]
[image]

Comment: when I created flex instance it is not showing what instance class it is, any help here ? because for me the pricing is going high, some how I am trying to reduce pricing. screenshot for your reference https://drive.google.com/file/d/17H1UqDDmHtaLSGF_Bz7R_ex4-hjJrHm_/view

Comment: looks like a bug, check your app.yaml to see instance type

Comment: in app.yaml file i have env: flex , there is no instance class mentioned.

Comment: so you have the default one, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml

Answer (score 2):

The information has moved again a year or so ago. Once logged in the Cloud Console, go to App Engine > Versions.

Select the service you would like information on:
[image: App Engine > Versions service selection]

Then scroll on the far right and you will see the "Config" column with on each version a link to "view" the configuration:
[image: App Engine > Versions config column]

Clicking on "View" will give you the configuration, including the instance_class:
[image: App Engine > Versions instance class on overlay]

Answer (score 1):

Select App Engine in the left menu, then Instances.

EDIT (July 2017)

Now this information is available in Versions tab (see @glmvrml answer).

Comment: But where do I see the instance types (F2, F4 etc.)?

Comment: This is the only information available in the console. You can no longer set instance types, etc. in the console - it has to be done in module description files.

Comment: Yes, I did that - but I wanted to check if the settings have been accepted. So I guess this feature has been removed.

Comment: There is an icon to provide feedback at the top of the console. I suggest that you tell Google to add this feature back.

Comment: The other answer provided (by @glmvrml) is correct - one can see the Instance Class of each Instance by going to App Engine -> Versions -> Show All Columns.  His answer should be chosen as the Correct one.

Comment: My answer was given 18 months ago :) The console changes from time to time.